# Subscript $Q$ in $U(1)_Q$

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, notation

In most quantum field theory books, you read something like

> QED is a QFT from Abelian $U(1)_Q$ that describes the electromagnetic interaction ...

But what does the subscript $Q$ stands for in the $U(1)_Q$ group?

Comment: Q is electric charge, Y weak hypercharge, B-L baryon minus lepton number charge, etc....

Comment: Thank you very much Cosmas!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It specifies that one is referring specifically to the symmetry associated with electromagnetism ($Q$ stands for electric charge, but some texts also write $U(1)_{\text{EM}}$, for example). This is meant to distinguish from other possible $U(1)$ symmetries present in the theory or in related theories that correspond to other physical aspects.

For example, in the Standard Model of Particle Physics, one has the gauge group $SU(3)_{C} \times SU(2)_{L} \times U(1)_{Y}$. Notice there is a $U(1)$ factor in there. One of the interactions described by this theory is electromagnetism. However, the generator of $U(1)_Q$ (and hence the boson associated with it, which is the photon) is not the generator of $U(1)_Y$. In fact, due to a process of [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking) one ends up with a $U(1)$ symmetry whose generator is a linear combination of one generator of $SU(2)_L$ and one generator of $U(1)_Y$.

In short, sometimes there are other interesting $U(1)$ transformations in your theory, with different interpretations. To be clear about which transformation we mean, it is common to add a sub-index to the gauge group. This is the same reason $SU(3)_{C} \times SU(2)_{L} \times U(1)_{Y}$ has all these indices ($C$ means color, since it is associated with [QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics); $L$ means left, since the symmetry only transforms left-handed particles; $Y$ means [(weak) hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge), which is another sort of $U(1)$ transformation relevant in the Standard Model).

For an extra example, the neutrinos have weak hypercharge -1 (this relates to $U(1)_Y$), but they have zero electric charge (this relates to $U(1)_Q$). This is not a problem, since these are two different symmetries, both associated with a $U(1)$ group.

Comment: Hi Nickolas, thank you so much for the detailed explanation, that makes so much sense now!

Answer (score -1):

In another way of describing $Q$ as a conserved charge under $U(1)$ symmetry which could be explained by Noether's theorem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).